# Conditionally paste strings together

Tags: r

The data I have is a vector with sentences cut into pieces.

```
y <- c("G'day", "world and everybody", "else.", "How's life?", "Hope", "you're", "doing just", "fine.")
```

I'd like to put the sentences back together.

Expected result:

```
y
[1] "G'day world and everybody else."
[2] "How's life?"
[3] "Hope you're doing just fine."
```

The 'rule' for there to be a sentence is that it starts with an upper-case letter. Building on this rule, what I've tried so far is this (but the result is anything but satisfactory):

```
unlist(strsplit(paste0(y[which(grepl("^[A-Z]", y))], " ", y[which(grepl("^[a-z]", y))], collapse = ","), ","))
[1] "G'day world and everybody" "How's life? else."         "Hope you're"               "G'day doing just"         
[5] "How's life? fine."
```

**EDIT**:

Have come up with this solution, which does give the expected result but looks ugly:

```
y1 <-  c(paste0(y[grepl("^[A-Z].*[^.?]$", y, perl = T)], " ", unlist(strsplit(paste0(y[which(grepl("^[a-z]", y))], collapse = " "), "\\."))), y[grepl("^[A-Z].*[.?]$", y, perl = T)])

y1
[1] "G'day world and everybody else" "Hope  you're doing just fine"   "How's life?"
```

What better solution is there?

**EDIT 2**:

Also a good solution is this:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(paste(y, collapse = " "), "[A-Z][^.?]*(\\.|\\?)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `gsub` to insert a new line before each capital, then split at new lines:

```r
unlist(strsplit(gsub(" ([A-Z])", "\n\\1", paste(y, collapse = " ")), "\n"))
#> [1] "G'day world and everybody else." "How's life?"                    
#> [3] "Hope you're doing just fine."
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This is embarrassingly cleverer than my solution ;)!